# How I can offer a local-only domain resolution once I run docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, internal-dns

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
  networks:
    frontend:
      ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
    outgoing:
      ipv4_address: 172.20.1.5
  volumes:
    - "./configuration/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
    - "./configuration/service-local.key:/etc/nginx/service-local.key:ro"
    - "./configuration/service-local.crt:/etc/nginx/service-local.crt:ro"
    - "website:/var/www/html/website"
    - "api:/var/www/html/api"
  extra_hosts:
    - "api:172.20.0.3"
    - "website:172.20.0.4"

  api:
    image: php
      volumes:
        - "api:/var/www/html/api"
      networks:
        - frontend
      extra_hosts:
        - "api.local:172.20.0.5"
      dns:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 9.9.9.9
      networks:
        frontend:
          ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
  
  website:
    image: php
      volumes:
        - "api:/var/www/html/api"
      networks:
        - frontend
      extra_hosts:
        - "api.local:172.20.0.5"
      dns:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 9.9.9.9
      networks:
        frontend:
          ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4
volumes:
  website:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
      o: "bind"
      device: $WEBSITE_DIR
  api:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
      o: "bind"
      device: $API_DIR

networks:
  backend:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24

  frontend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24
```

All the incoming traffic will pass through `frontend` traffic.
The setup above is used for app development in my local machine.

For development we use the following hostnames placed diurectly in `/etc/hosts` or each `hosts` file of every developer:

- `api.local` for the api executed in api container.
- `website.local` for the actual website executed in `website` container.

Also I have an android app where I use it for mobile app testing that use the domains above. How I can provide some sort of DNS for my apps in a specific network served from each developer's machine?